# ToList() doesn't apply dynamically generated where clauses Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

ToList() doesn't apply dynamically generated where clauses Asp.Net Core
I am building pipeline for filtering. so i have method where i retrieve iqueryable from dbcontext, it looks like the following:

```
 public IEnumerable<Event> Filter(EventFilterModel filterModel)
    {
        _filterManager = new EventsSelectionPipeline();
        _filterManager.Register(new EventTypeFilter(filterModel.EventTypes, _unitOfWork));

        var events = _unitOfWork.DbContext.Events;
        var filteredEvents = _filterManager.Process(events);

        return filteredEvents.ToList();
    }
```

Process method:

```
public override IQueryable<Event> Process(IQueryable<Event> input)
    {
        foreach(var filter in _filters)
        {
            filter.Execute(input);
        }

        return input;
    }
```

EventTypeFilter :

```
public class EventTypeFilter : IFilter<IQueryable<Event>>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<EnumEventType> _eventTypes;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<ApplicationContext> _unitOfWork;

    public EventTypeFilter(IEnumerable<EnumEventType> eventTypes, IUnitOfWork<ApplicationContext> uow)
    {
        _eventTypes = eventTypes;
        _unitOfWork = uow;
    }

    public IQueryable<Event> Execute(IQueryable<Event> input)
    {
        if (_eventTypes.Any())
        {
            BinaryExpression condition = null;
            var expr = new List<Expression<Func<Event, bool>>>();
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Event), "ev");

            foreach(var eventType in _eventTypes)
            {
                var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "EventType");
                var propType = ((PropertyInfo)property.Member).PropertyType;
                var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propType);

                var propertyValue = eventType;
                var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
                var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propType);
                var dynExpr = Expression.Equal(property, valueExpression);

                condition = condition == null ? dynExpr : Expression.Or(condition, dynExpr);
            }

            if(condition != null)
            {
                var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Event, bool>>(condition, parameter);

                input = input.Where(predicate);
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

In `IQueryable<Event> Process(IQueryable<Event> input)` method Execute return iqueryable with correct number of elements (with applying filtering), but when i apply toList to iqueryable it just returns me initial set of data without filtering.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you clarify what your question is here?

Comment: `ToList()` applies to the *results* of the enumerable or queryable, including the `Where` clause. If you don't get the results you expected check your code. You are probably *missing* the `Where` clause

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In Process method, input after foreach with where clause but when i make ToList in Filter it's just doesn't apply

Comment: @Gozaph it does apply. As long as there are any `Where` clauses in there. If it doesn't, it means there aren't any filters. `Where()` returns a *new* IEnumerable<T> or IQueryable<T> with the filter condition. Your code though discards it immediatelly and uses the original IQueryable

Comment: BTW what is the point of this code? Why not just add `Where()` clauses with the lambas you want, eg `events=events.Where(SomeConditionLambda)`? The `EventTypeFilter` class tries to do the same thing an `Expression<Func<T,Boolean>>` would do.

Comment: The whole point of using LINQ is that you *don't* have to construct filters like this. You provide an expression to the `Where()` or `Select()` calls instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember the filtered query:

```
public override IQueryable<Event> Process(IQueryable<Event> input)
{
    foreach(var filter in _filters)
    {
        input = filter.Execute(input);
    }

    return input;
}
```

If you want to avoid having to assign the result back to the original query, you can also pass the query by reference:

```
public void Execute(ref IQueryable<Event> input)
{
    if (_eventTypes.Any())
    {
        //...

        if(condition != null)
        {
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Event, bool>>(condition, parameter);

            input = input.Where(predicate);
        }
    }
}

//...

public override IQueryable<Event> Process(IQueryable<Event> input)
{
    foreach(var filter in _filters)
    {
        filter.Execute(ref input);
    }

    return input;
}
```

This would allow to apply the filter in a more "natural" way, while the first option is more flexible, since it lets you keep the initial query.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter.Execute(input);
```

this should probably be

```
input = filter.Execute(input);
```

Otherwise, your filters don't "stick".

Comment: but filter it is not return IQueryable. It returns IFilter<IQueryable<Event>>

Comment: @Gozaph then you'll have to change it. `Where()` returns a new IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<>, it doesn't modify an existing one.